# Não é possível converter DBNull.Value no tipo 'System.Decimal'. Use um tipo anulável

Tags: c#, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um Sistema a qual retorna valores feitos no dia, Pegando todos os valores retornados entre a data de hoje, podendo filtrar com outras datas. Trata-se de um fluxo de caixa. O problema que encontro é o seguinte:

```
//Pegando valores de um DateTimePicker e convertendo para tipo DateTime (MYSQL)
string data1 = dtp_Data1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string data2 = dtp_Data2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

//Faço o Select

string EntradaTotalDinheiro = String.Format(@"
            SELECT SUM(valor_total) AS total 
            FROM tb_caixa
            WHERE tipo_movimentacao = 'ENTRADA' AND forma = 'DINHEIRO'
            AND data between '" + data1 + "' and '" + data2 + "'");
            DataTable dinheiro = Banco.dql(EntradaTotalDinheiro);

//Passo o valor para minha label
lb_TotalDinheiro.Text = dinheiro.Rows[0].Field<decimal>("total").ToString("C");
```

O problema está ai. Este comando está em um botão mas gostaria de coloca-lo até em um DGV.
Só que se for executado no início do dia por exemplo, não haverá nenhum registro na minha tabela, então ele retornará nulo. E vai ocorrer o erro que se encontra no titulo.

```
if (Banco.dql(EntradaTotalDinheiro) != null)
{
   lb_TotalDinheiro.Text = dinheiro.Rows[0].Field<decimal>("total").ToString("C");
}
```

Já tentei Ifs como esse e não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Tentou usar COALESCE ? SELECT  COALESCE(SUM(valor_total),0) AS total    https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp

Comment: Um ISNULL no SUM não resolve? ISNULL(SUM(valor_total), 0)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a forma mais fácil para a solução deste problema é fazer um **coalesce** no valor, onde caso o campo retorne **null** você pode alterar para **outro valor**.

Seu código ficaria:

```
string EntradaTotalDinheiro = String.Format(@"
            SELECT COALESCE(SUM(valor_total), 0) AS total 
            FROM tb_caixa
            WHERE tipo_movimentacao = 'ENTRADA' AND forma = 'DINHEIRO'
            AND data between '" + data1 + "' and '" + data2 + "'");
```

Outra alternativa seria tratar o erro com o DBNULL.

Comment: Consegui fazer com IFNULL !!! definindo que se for nullo será retornado 0